# React Logging out user on 401 response throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

Logging out a user on 401 response from API throws error

Profile page

```
    let { token, logoutUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    let getProfile = async () => {
    
    let response = await fetch("/profile/me/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Token " + String(token),
    },
  });
    if (response.status === 401) {
      console.log("Should Log out")
      logoutUser()
      
    }
    else {
      let data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setProfile(data);
    }
    
  }

  useEffect(() => getProfile(), [])
```

AuthContext
logoutUser functions, sets token state to null, removes token from local storage and then navigates back to home

```
    let logoutUser = () => {
        setToken(null)
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        navigate("/");
    }
    
    let contextData = {
        loginUser: loginUser,
        token: token,
        logoutUser: logoutUser,
    }
```

I'm getting this error but reloading the page works normally and the logout button on navbar works fine as well

```
Should Log out
react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: n is not a function

at tu (react-dom.production.min.js:240:251)
at ru (react-dom.production.min.js:244:163)
at Ss (react-dom.production.min.js:284:388)
at react-dom.production.min.js:282:391
at k (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
at MessagePort.j (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)

di @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
react-dom.production.min.js:127 Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function
at tu (react-dom.production.min.js:240:251)
at ru (react-dom.production.min.js:244:163)
at Ss (react-dom.production.min.js:284:388)
at react-dom.production.min.js:282:391
at k (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
at MessagePort.j (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was because of the way I used useEffect, you should include the async function inside the useEffect and call it from there too

```
useEffect(() => {

  async function fetchData() {
  let response = await fetch(`/profile/me/`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Token " + String(token),
      },
    }
  );
  if (response.status === 401) {
    logoutUser();  
  } 
  else {
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setProfile(data);
  }
}
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

More information about this can be found [here](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect)

Also as I didn't know this but will note it here just in case anyone else is facing the same issues, if you are using react and django, it's better if you run them as separate servers, at least during development, this way you can do changes to both codes and it will apply automatically without having to build the project again and if any errors are thrown, it is much easier to debug them not like the gibberish error above